# uniqueness for non homogenous heat equation

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

hi in nonhomogenous heat equation :$u_{t}-\Delta u=f(x,t)$ in U smooth open of $R^{n}$  and $f \in L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(U))$  with $u_{0}$ in $L^{2}(U)$,$u=0$ in $\partial U$
i find that u $\in C((0,T),L^{2}(U)) \cap L^{2}((0,T),H_{0}^{1}(U))$ and i wanted to prove uniqueness but in the hint thay say that $u_{t}\in  L^{2}((0,T),H_{0}^{1}(U)\cap H^{2}(U))$ i can prove that but my question is why it's a a condition to prove uniqueness? thanks

Comment: By linearity it suffices to show that the only solution corresponding to $f=0$ and $u_0=0$ is $u=0$. For this prove a global energy inequality by e.g. testing the equation against itself. This should require some regularity of $\partial_tu$ to derive, hence the hint.